# Create a cumulative comparison table in PHP and MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays, loops

I have a database table called payments which contains date,amount fields. I want to take values from amount field and SUM up all amounts by date and take the results to html table then output them like on the image.

I have created dates dynamically so that they will be equal nomatter which months example January its 1-31 and February its 1-31. Where there is a weekend or the date is invalid i want the value to be zero. What i want is like this table  [table][1] [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMOl3.jpg

This is what i am getting [output][1][1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJpyT.jpg

******NOTE***** I THINK MY SOLUTION IS NOT THE BEST SOLUTION TO MY PROBLEM. IF POSSIBLE JUST TAKE I VIEW ON THE PICTURE WHICH I WANT AND FIND ME THE BEST SOLUTION. I WANT TO BE HELPED IN EITHER STEPS TO ACHIEVE  IT OR A SOLUTION

I know that i am using a depricated mysql synthax please ignore that and help on my problem.

```
<table border="1" align="center">
  <?php
    session_start();
    include("connection/db_con.php");
    $sym='-';
    $d=array();
    ///Insert values of month for period selected into an array
    $a = $_POST['dat'];
    $b = $_POST['dat2'];
    $mnth=array();
    $m_nam=array();
    $m_nm=array();
    $m_nam[]="Day";
    //////New way of getting months in format Y-m
    $start    = new DateTime($a);
    $start->modify('first day of this month');
    $end      = new DateTime($b);
    $end->modify('first day of next month');
    $interval = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 month');
    $period   = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

    foreach ($period as $dt) {
      $mnth[]=$dt->format("Y-m");
      $m_nam[]=date('F-Y', strtotime($dt->format("Y-m")));
      $m_nm[]=date('M', strtotime($dt->format("Y-m")));
    }
    ///////End of New way
    echo "<tr bgcolor='#999999'>";
    foreach ($m_nam as $m)
    {
      echo"<td>".$m."</td>";
    }
    echo"</tr>";
    /////////End insert////////////////////////
    $day=0;
    for($x=1; $x<=31; $x++)
    {
      $day=$day+1;
      echo"<tr>";
      echo"<td>".$day."</td>";
      $d=$sym.$x;

      foreach($mnth as $mon)
      {
        $dat=$mon.$d;

        $qry=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_disb FROM payments where dat='$dat'")or die(mysql_error());
        $row=mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
        $sum = $row['total_disb']+0;

        echo"<td>".$sum."</td>";

      }
      echo"</tr>";
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

Comment: From the output screenshot that you've provided, is it correct to assume that you have managed to output the daily amount and are missing the cumulative amounts?

Comment: Yes that is very correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a rewrite of the code you provided, it's using dummy random data instead of DB and there is no logic for POST variables, but that you can replace with your code.

```
<?php   
  // session start, db connection goes here  
  echo '<table border="1" align="center">';
  // Example of post vars
  $start = new DateTime('2015-11-10');
  $end = new DateTime('2016-02-28');
  // Note: not sure why OP used modify here
  $interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
  $daterange = new DatePeriod($start, $interval, $end);

  // Table Header row 1
  echo '<tr><th>Day</th>';
  foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    echo '<th colspan="2">'.$date->format("F Y").'</th>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';

  // Temporary month store
  $months = array();

  // Table Header row 2
  echo '<tr style="background-color:#22bb22;"><th></th>';
  foreach ($daterange as $date) {
    $months[] =  $date->format("F");
    echo '<th>Daily</th>';
    echo '<th>Cumulative</th>';
  }
  echo '</tr>';

  // Table Body
  $sumc = array();
  for ($d = 1; $d <= 31; $d++) {
    echo '<tr><td>'.$d.'</td>';
    foreach ($months as $month) {
      $db_date = $month.'-'.$d; // used for db query
      // dummmy data (replace with db query result)
      $sum = mt_rand(0, 999);
      echo '<td>'.$sum.'</td>';
      if(!array_key_exists($month, $sumc)) {
        $sumc[$month] = 0;
      }
      $sumc[$month] = (int)$sum + $sumc[$month];
      echo '<td>'.$sumc[$month].'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';  
  }

  echo '</table>';
?>
```

Also the condition:

> Where there is a weekend or the date is invalid i want the value to be
>   zero.

is it correct to assume that these are taken care because the DB query would return 0? Or do you have to check in the code for weekends even if the DB query returns an amount from total_disb that is >0?

Comment: flacle you are the best this is exactly what i needed. I wanted to up vote this answer but i am not able to do so because of my reputation. Thanks a lot for the effort man.

Comment: Your assumption is correct @flacle. And this worked i just changed the $months[] to hold date in format $date->format("Y-m")

Comment: @Leereal glad it worked :) maybe you do have the privilege to accept this one as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have just messed up a little with dates, if I'm understanding where your problem is you can do it directly from SQL, try something like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_disb , MONTH(DateTime) , DAY(DateTime)
FROM payments   
GROUP BY DATE(DateTime), DAY(DateTime)
```

Change DateTime for your variable or column names.

If you also want to SUM the months totals at the end of the table I'd recommend you to make a new query like:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_disb , MONTH(DateTime)
FROM payments   
GROUP BY DATE(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime)
```

Another option would be to increment a variable while you loop to print the values, but in my opinion a new query is more simple.

If this is not what you need leave a comment and I will edit it.

Comment: I think the date issue is not a problem but the cumulative part.

Comment: @Leereal So you want to SUM all the amounts in a certain period of time?

Comment: i want to add up all amount totals of same month but its adding up amount of same day of different month. That is its adding up 2015-11-01 to 2015-12-01 which is not what i want. I want it to add 2015-11-01 to 2015-11-02. I think there is a better way somewhere to do this. But i want my days to be from 1 to 31 nomatter which month.

Comment: to get what i mean can you forget about the code and look at the image which i want compared to what i have

Comment: @Leereal There you go, that should return something really similar of what you have in the desired table. You just need to add some HTML marking to that query result and you will have your table

Answer (score 0):

To get to the cumulative you have to store the previous sum result and add it to the current iteration in the loop, something like:

```
$sumc = array();
foreach($mnth as $mon) {
    $dat = $mon . $d;
    $qry = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total_disb FROM payments where dat='$dat'") or die(mysql_error());
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($qry);
    $sum = $row['total_disb'];
    if(isset($sumc[$mon])) {
      $sumc[$mon] = (int)$sum + $sumc[$mon];
    } else {
      $sumc[$mon] = (int)$sum;
    }
    echo "<td>" . $sum . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $sumc[$mon] . "</td>";
}
```

should probably work.

(Note: that you are missing a second row for 'daily' and 'cumulative' and once you have that row you need to use `colspan` to span the columns of the Months across). See an example of colspan [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_td_colspan).

Comment: Your idea is right but i want to add up all amount totals of same month but its adding up amount of same day of different month. That is its adding up 2015-11-01 to 2015-12-01 which is not what i want. I want it to add 2015-11-01 to 2015-11-02

Comment: I think there is a better way to do so than mine.

Comment: @Leereal right, your Months are horizontal, I am thinking what would be a way to keep it simple, assuming that you need to have the months aligned horizontally. I have an idea, let me update the code.

Comment: Yes i want months to be horizontal according to date which i selected and days to be fixed vertically from 1-31 check my images i think i am doing it the wrong way. Get me the best way to do it. But consider my dates from 1 to 31 always nomatter the month

Comment: Ok, guess not yet approved @Leereal the idea is to declare an array outside of the for loop and populate this array using a month as a key in each iteration. So `$sumc[$mon] = (int)$sum + $sumc[$mon];` you have to test if the key is set for the first rows with `if(isset($sumc[$mon]))` else you might get a PHP notice of undefined index.

Comment: i guess you have what i want in your mind. Just look at the images that i uploaded. The first one is what i want. So can you tell me the steps to follow to get to that output. My code is completely wrong.

Comment: What you have posted should work first before you can begin to optimise ;) Try the solution with array using `$mon` as the key, once you have what you want you can try to rewrite the code for a more optimal solution.

Comment: i tried it and its not working. Its output is always zero. Can we try something else. Which can give me results

Comment: Ok, I can see later if I can work out something but can't guarantee it at the moment.

Comment: @Leereal see new answer :)